# including test-jar in the runtime scope

Tags: maven, maven-3

i got a `war`-project and in the `test-jar` of it, we have aside of the jUnit testcases also the mocks to the neighbor systems (for instance, the roles and users management system).
and we have a maven profile called `mocking` that adds the `test-jar` dependency to the `war`-project, at `runtime`, so that the mocks are available for the developer, but do not end up by error in production.

```
<profile>
    <id>mocking</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
...
```

not very clean, i know, but we did not want to have just another artifact for only a hand full of mock clases, and it worked so far well with Maven 3.3.9.

now we need a feature of Maven 3.5.0, so i updated to the latest Maven 3.6.2 and get following error:

```
The project com.my-project:web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT has 1 error:
'dependencies.dependency.[com.my-project:web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]' for com.my-project:web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is referencing itself.
```

which is kind of borderline case. 
imho, and since the dependency is of scope `runtime`, it should be allowed.

is this a bug?

can anyone figure out a better way to achieve this?

many thanks

Michael

---

UPDATE 20191125:

> Without full pom files or at least an example which looks very like your original projects it's hard to guess....

Here a small pom-file to reproduce the problem:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

with that file, and nothing else, `mvn compile` works fine with v3.3.9 but breaks with v3.6.2

Comment: To address a test-jar you need also the `<classifier>tests</classifier>`...

Comment: @khmarbaise: thanks for the hint, but it sadly did not help

Comment: Without full pom files or at least an example which looks very like your original projects it's hard to guess....

Comment: @khmarbaise: i updated the question with a working example, thanks

Comment: As I already wrote you need to add the `classifier` based on the error message `or com.my-project:web:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is referencing itself.`...it shows there is something else wrong...please make a full working example on Github...

Comment: @khmarbaise: indeed, now i got it working. `classifier` did the trick, not sure why my first try did not work. do you mind to write an answer?

Comment: Done so. See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the normal setup for creating a `test-jar` this implies the `test-jar` is created as supplemental artifact to your usual artifacts which needed to be distinguished from each other which has to be achieved by using the `<classifier>tests</classifier>`.